# Ajax call to retrieve json file data

Tags: json, ajax, linux

I am trying to get data from a json file using Ajax call. But whenever Ajax tries to read from the file the server responds with error, 500 premature end of script.

The json file is kept at /cgi-bin/ directory. I am using Apache http web server. As I am new to web technologies, could any one please help how to further proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's likely not a JSON file, but rather a script that is generating a JSON output.

The error seems to indicate that there is an error with the program generating JSON.

If it is indeed a `.json` file you're attempting to get, try moving the file to your `htdocs` (or whatever your document root is) instead.

Comment: I copied my json file root directory ie. /htdocs/ and tried reading it, then I got error prompting "The requested URL was not found on this server". Although, the url is updated, still its not reading that.

Comment: It worked. I created an alias for htdocs in httpd conf and gave the directory  path. Thanks Paul.